# geom_text_repel() no me sale bien

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un dataset "premier" de la liga inglesa del 2018. He filtrado para quedarme solo con los valores del Chelsea y he elaborado un sencillo gráfico con x=minutos totales e y=goles concedidos. El problema viene cuando quiero colocar los nombres de los jugadores "full_name" en los puntos de la gráfica. Si lo hago así, me da bien:

```
ggplot(data = Chelsea,
           mapping = aes(x=minutes_played_overall,
                         y=conceded_overall,
                         colour="blue",
                         label=full_name)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_text(aes(label=full_name),hjust=0, vjust=0))
```

pero quedan interpuestos y me gustaría saber como usar correctamente geom_text_repel en esta ocasión.

```
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(Chelsea) +
  geom_point(aes(minutes_played_overall, conceded_overall), color = 'red') +
  geom_text_repel(aes(minutes_played_overall, conceded_overall, label = full_name)) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

me da error "Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?"

Comment: Hola Zenit, nos podrías compartir un ejemplo de la base que estas utilizando para que se mas fácil poder ayudarte

Comment: Chelsea? Buuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu. :P  || Ya en serio, añade tus datos de prueba para que otros puedan probar tu código y ayudarte